# Restoring SQL Server filegroup subset

Tags: sql-server, restore

Struggling with a task I've been given. We have a large SQL Server 2012 database (almost 2TB) with multiple filegroups. The filegroups are basically split up into different years, so many of them contain older data. The tables also contain 'image' data. All filegroups are read/write and the database is used 24/7. My task is to restore only the PRIMARY and current year's filegroups to a different instance of SQL. We do full, diff, and log backups on a regular schedule and I'm able to restore individual filegroups to the other instance. However, I'm unable to bring the database online unless I restore all filegroups.

In the past we've been doing a full restore to the other environment then removing what we don't need. This ends up taking longer than is acceptable now and uses too much disk space. Is there anyway for me to only restore the filegroups I need and still bring the database back online? Any and all help is greatly appreciated.  

Comment: All capital nicks look bad on the first spot, I suggest to become simply "Joat DBA".

Comment: You are referring to a [piece meal restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/piecemeal-restores-sql-server). The limitation there is you only have read access, you cannot make any changes to that partially restored database